Solve an integral, e.g, $I = \int_{p}^{p+\delta p} f(x) dx=\int_{p}^{p+\delta p}\frac{e^{ax}(1-e^{-ax})}{x(1-x)}dx$
I am trying to solve an integral over an infinitesimal interval, such as:  $\begin{align}I = \int_{p}^{p+\delta p} f(x) dx=\int_{p}^{p+\delta p}\frac{e^{ax}(1-e^{-ax})}{x(1-x)}dx&\tag{1}\end{align}.$
Based on my understanding of a similar question in Seeking formal explanation of definite integral over infinitesimal interval, the solution would be:  $\begin{align}I = \int_{p}^{p+\delta p}\frac{e^{ax}(1-e^{-ax})}{x(1-x)}dx=\frac{e^{ap}(1-e^{-ap})}{p(1-p)}&\tag{2}\end{align}.$
Is it correct? What are your thoughts on that?

That question is essentially after the derivative of an integral. You're not dividing your result by $\delta p$, so for ordinary functions (i.e., not something like the Dirac delta), your result should be just $0$, assuming I understand what you're getting at (and the interval $[p, p+\delta p]$ doesn't include $0$ or $1$ or something like that).

Yes, this is the post I refer to in my question. I corrected the $dp$ with $dx$, so I think that my solution is correct. Yes?

Do you have any information on $p$? Because $p=1$ creates a problem in the denominator.

yes, so $p$ can only get values between 0 and 1 (0 and 1 excluded).

No, it is not correct.

By your comment, you consider $p\in(0,1)$. Then there exists an $\varepsilon>0$, such that $[p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon]\subset(0,1)$.
Moreover, the function
$$f:[p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon]\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad  f(x):=\frac{e^{ax}(1-e^{-ax})}{x(1-x)}$$
is continuous and by the fundamental theorem of calculus, you find that
$$F(x):=\int^x_{p-\varepsilon}f(s)ds$$
is continuous on $[p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon]$ and differentiable on $(p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon)$ with derivative
$$f(p)=F'(p)$$
Especially, it holds
$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\delta p}\int_{p}^{p+\delta p}f(s)ds=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(p+\delta p)-F(p)}{\delta p}=F'(p)=f(p)$$

Your question is different, though. You are asking for the value of
$$\int_{p}^{p+\delta p} f(s)ds=F(p+\delta p)- F(p)$$
for an infinitesimally small interval $[p, p+\delta p]$.
This value tends to go to $0$, since $F$ is continuous at $p$.

The question that you have linked to suggests that for an infinitesimal $\delta p$,
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\int_{p}^{p+\delta p}\dfrac{e^{ax}(1-e^{-ax})}{x(1-x)}dx}{\delta p}
 = \frac{e^{ap}(1-e^{-ap})}{p(1-p)}. 
$$
But you have written
$$
\displaystyle\int_{p}^{p+\delta p}\dfrac{e^{ax}(1-e^{-ax})}{x(1-x)}dx
 \stackrel?= \frac{e^{ap}(1-e^{-ap})}{p(1-p)}. 
$$
Can you see what is different between these two equations?

yes, thank you. This is what @user408858 was implying.

One can integrate over an infinitesimal interval as follows.  Integration over an interval $[a,b]$ can be thought  of as a map $Int: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathcal L$ where $\mathcal L$ is the space of endomorphisms of continuous functions, sending the pair $(a,b)$ to the endomorphism $f \mapsto \int_a^b f(x)dx$.  By the transfer principle, we have the star-transform ${}^\ast Int : {}^\ast \mathbb R \times {}^\ast \mathbb R \to {}^\ast L$.  In this way, integration is now defined for hyperreal values of $a,b$, and in particular when they are infinitely close and form an interval of infinitesimal length.
The function you are integrating does not seem to have an easy antiderivative in closed form, but if you decompose it using partial fractions, one of the components will be the function $\frac{1}{x}$ so I will illustrate what happens for that function.  Its antiderivative is $\ln x$ and therefore the integral over the hyperreal interval with endpoints $p$ and $p+\delta p$ will be $\ln (p+\delta p) - \ln p$, which is about $\frac{\delta p}{p}$ up to higher-order infinitesimals.  For your function $f(x)$, one would get $f(p)\,\delta p$ up to higher-order infinitesimals.  Thus one can be more specific than saying that "This value tends to go to 0".
